# Constructor reference for inner class fails with VerifyError at runtime

Tags: java, lambda, inner-classes, java-8, constructor-reference

I am creating a supplier for an inner class constructor using the lambda `ctx -> new SpectatorSwitcher(ctx)`. IntelliJ suggested that I change it to `SpectatorSwitcher::new` instead. SpectatorSwitcher is a non-static inner class of the class I'm working in. The suggested code compiles fine (using maven) but I get the following VerifyError on execution:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    Test.lambda$runTest$8(LTest$Worker;)V @2: invokedynamic
  Reason:
    Type 'Test$Worker' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'Test'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @2
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'Test$Worker' }
    stack: { 'Test$Worker', 'Test$Worker' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a2a ba00 0b00 00b6 000c b1            

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2937)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1771)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
```

Why is javac / maven not failing while compiling but still producing invalid byte code?

**Edit:** The problem appears to be far more complex than the simple call, this is the code needed to reproduce it:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

/**
 * @author Yawkat
 */
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) { new Test().runTest(); }

    private void runTest() {
        Worker worker = new Worker();
        run(() -> worker.print(field -> new SomeClass(field)));
        run(() -> worker.print(SomeClass::new));
    }

    private void run(Runnable runnable) {
        runnable.run();
    }

    private class SomeClass {
        final Object field;

        SomeClass(Object field) {
            this.field = field;
        }
    }

    private static class Worker {
        void print(Function<Object, Object> i) {
            System.out.println(i.apply(null));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us a small reproducible code snippet?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I had to do some more research because the code needed is far more complex than I thought. I added it.

Comment: Looks like a JVM bug. Please consider filing a bug report.

Comment: It's a javac bug, not a JVM bug. See comment thread on Rohit Jain's answer.

Answer (score 10):

Even after smacking my head into the bytecode for almost an hour, I've not been able to come to a reasonable conclusion as to why this is happening. Surprisingly, changing your method to this:

```
private void runTest() {
    Worker worker = new Worker();
    run(() -> worker.print(field -> new SomeClass(field)));
    Function<Object, Object> function = SomeClass::new;
    run(() -> worker.print(function));
}
```

works fine. Also, getting rid of `run()` method invocation, and just calling `worker.print()`:

```
private void runTest() {
    Worker worker = new Worker();
    worker.print(field -> new SomeClass(field));
    worker.print(SomeClass::new);
}
```

also works.

It seems like, using the constructor reference as in your case is not able to pass the enclosing instance of `Test` class to the `SomeClass` constructor which is required. While the two cases here are able to pass `Test` instance to the `SomeClass` constructor.

But I couldn't come to the exact reason. The above reasoning might very well be wrong. But I've just come to that after getting to those working approach.

You might want to go through [lambda translation](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html), to understand the inner working. I'm still not very much clear about how lambdas and method references are translated.

I found a [thread in lambda mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-September/005938.html) about similar issue. Also, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13219297/1679863) is also related.

The following `runtTest()` method:

```
public void runTest() {
    Worker worker = new Worker();
    run(() -> worker.print((field) -> new SomeClass(field)));
    run(() -> worker.print(SomeClass::new));

    Function<Object, Object> func = SomeClass::new;
    run(() -> worker.print(func));

    worker.print(SomeClass::new);
}
```

Is compiled to following bytecode:

```
  public void runTest();
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class SO$Worker
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method SO$Worker."<init>":()V
       7: astore_1
       8: aload_0
       9: aload_0
      10: aload_1
      11: invokedynamic #4,  0              // InvokeDynamic #0:run:(LSO;LSO$Worker;)Ljava/lang/Runnable;
      16: invokevirtual #5                  // Method run:(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
      19: aload_0
      20: aload_1
      21: invokedynamic #6,  0              // InvokeDynamic #1:run:(LSO$Worker;)Ljava/lang/Runnable;
      26: invokevirtual #5                  // Method run:(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
      29: aload_0
      30: invokedynamic #7,  0              // InvokeDynamic #2:apply:(LSO;)Ljava/util/function/Function;
      35: astore_2
      36: aload_0
      37: aload_1
      38: aload_2
      39: invokedynamic #8,  0              // InvokeDynamic #3:run:(LSO$Worker;Ljava/util/function/Function;)Ljava/lang/Runnable;
      44: invokevirtual #5                  // Method run:(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
      47: aload_1
      48: aload_0
      49: invokedynamic #7,  0              // InvokeDynamic #2:apply:(LSO;)Ljava/util/function/Function;
      54: invokevirtual #9                  // Method SO$Worker.print:(Ljava/util/function/Function;)V
      57: return
```

I can see only the second `run()` method invocation doesn't pass `LSO` argument, while others do pass it. You can run the command - `javap -c -s -verbose Test`, to see Bootstrap methods for `#0`, `#1`, etc. I guess we can definitely say that this is a bug. Perhaps you can file one.

Comment: I have submitted a bug report for this.

Comment: @yawkat Please add the link to the bug report in your question.

Comment: @yawkat and Rohit, thanks for tracking this down and filing a bug. Tinkering around with this kind of code, it's fairly easy to get the compiler to crash with NPE. There's definitely a bug in javac here. It looks like there is already a bug in the JDK bug database for this: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8037404 .