# Difference between stream().map() and stream.map({}) in java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Yesterday i stumbled over something i neither really understand nor i'm able to find an explanation:

Consider the following operations:

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).map(i -> i * 2).forEach(System.out::println);

//This one won't compile
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).map(i -> { i * 2; }).forEach(System.out::println);
```

It appears that the second one can be extended to

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).map(i -> { return i * 2;}).forEach(System.out::println);
```

and it will just compile fine. I came up with this because i'm kinda used to the first version but my IDE (Netbeans) always refers to the last version.

So my Question is: *What* is the difference/advantage of these two implementations? And why does the one with the `{}` block requires a return value? Where is the need for that value (except to make the code compile)?

**Update:**

With respect to [When are braces optional in Java 8 lambda syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145696/when-are-braces-optional-in-java-8-lambda-syntax), this one can't be about lambda expression syntax only because

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).forEach(i -> { System.out.println(i); });
```

compiles fine, so is has to be(from my understading) about the implementation of `map()`.

Cheers, Ben

Comment: The "braceless" version requires that the right hand side of the arrow sign be a valid Java expression (note: expression, not statement!); this is why it works. But at the end both do the same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is the following:

A lambda expression looks like

```
parameters -> expression
```

or

```
parameters -> { block }
```

where either the `block` returns a value - or it doesn't for a `void`-like behaviour.

In other words, a `parameters -> expression` lambda is equivalent to `parameters -> { return expression; }` if `expression` has a non-void type or to `parameters -> { expression; }` if `expression` has void type (such as `System.out.printf()`).

Your first version essentially uses an expression with a bit of overhead:

`i -> i = i * 2` could be reduced to `i -> i * 2`, as the `i =` assignment is just unnecessary, because `i` disappears immediately afterwards without being used any further.

It is just like

```
Integer function(Integer i) {
    i = i * 2;
    return i;
}
```

or

```
Integer function(Integer i) {
    return (i = i * 2);
}
```

which can be simplified to

```
Integer function(Integer i) {
    return i * 2;
}
```

All these examples would match the interface `UnaryOperator<Integer>` which is a special case for `Function<Integer, Integer>`.

In contrast, you 2nd example is like

```
XY function(int i) {
    i = i * 2;
}
```

which doesn't work:

- Either `XY` is `void` (which would make a `Consumer<Integer>` which doesn't fit with `.map()`)
- Or `XY` is indeed `Integer` (then the return statement is missing).

> Where is the need for that value (except to make the code compile)?

Well, `.forEach(System.out::println);` needs that value...

So, everything which can be converted to a `Function<T, R>` can be given to a `.map()` of a `T` stream, resulting in an `R` stream:

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).map(i -> i * 2)
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).map(i -> { return i * 2; })
```

turn the `Integer` you give into another `Integer`, giving you another `Stream<Integer>`. You notice that they are boxed?

Other ways would be

```
// turn a Stream<Integer> to an IntStream with a 
// int applyAsInt(Integer i) aka ToIntFunction<Integer>
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).mapToInt(i -> i * 2)
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).mapToInt(i -> { return i * 2; })

// turn an IntStream to a different IntStream with a 
// int applyAsInt(int i) aka IntUnaryOperator
IntStream.of(1, 2, 3).map(i -> i * 2)
IntStream.of(1, 2, 3).map(i -> { return i * 2; })

// turn an IntStream to a Stream<Integer> with a 
// Integer apply(int i) aka IntFunction<Integer>
IntStream.of(1, 2, 3).mapToObj(i -> i * 2)
IntStream.of(1, 2, 3).mapToObj(i -> { return i * 2; })
```

All these examples have in common that they get a value and produce a value of either the same or a different type. (Note how these examples use AutoBoxing and AutoUnboxing as needed.)

OTOH, everything which can be converted to a `Consumer<T>` can be given to a `.map()` of a `T` stream, which can be any form of lambda which produces a `void` expression:

```
.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x))
.forEach(x -> { System.out.println(x); }) // no return as you cannot return a void expression
.forEach(System.out::println) // shorter syntax for the same thing
.forEach(x -> { }) // just swallow the value
```

With that in mind, it is easy to see that a lambda with `void` expression type cannot be given to `.map()`, and a lambda with a non-`void` type cannot be given to `forEach()`.

Comment: Well, even without a terminal `.forEach(System.out::println)`, the fact that `map(…)` expects a *Function* is enough to require the lambda expression to return a value…

Comment: I edited my question so you might want to edit your answer aswell :)

Comment: @BenWin I tried to shed some light on that and hope to have succeeded in that...

Comment: Thank you very much for giving that extensive and good answer!