# Iambda expression compilation error

Tags: java, lambda, concurrenthashmap

I am using search of ConcurrentHashMap like this:

```
map.search(1, (k, v) -> {  
  return v.size() > 10 ? k : null;
});
```

But when I remove braces it gives me compilation error:

```
map.search(1, (k, v) -> 
  return v.size() > 10 ? return k : null;
);
```

I want to remove braces since it is single statement in lambda expression.

Update : corrected typo

Comment: Then also remove `return`, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145696/when-are-braces-optional-in-java-8-lambda-syntax.

Comment: Try with: `->v.size() > 10 ? k : null`

Comment: @jensgram yes exactly that was the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A return statement is not an expression , its a statement. In lambda expression you must enclose statement in {} braces. For further details you can study here : 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#syntax

Answer (score 1):

As there are 2 return statements, you can either have the braces as you posted above:

```
map.search(1, (k, v) -> {  
return v.size() > 10 ? return k : null;
});
```

Or you need to remove the other return:

```
map.search(1, (k, v) -> {  
return v.size() > 10 ? k : null;
});
```

For further knowledge, you can visit the following link:

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#syntax