# StorageService gives an error on GluonHQ framework - How do I solve this?

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-mobile, javafxports

Normally I have been using FileChooser in JavaFX. Super easy to do that. Just call it and it will open a new window where you can select your file. Done!

But `FileChooser` does not work on Android and Iphone. I have to choose `StorageService` instead

https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.1/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/StorageService.html

```
File privateStorage = Services.get(StorageService.class)
                          .flatMap(StorageService::getPrivateStorage)
                          .orElseThrow(() -> {
                              new FileNotFoundException("Could not access private storage.");
                          });
```

But the problem here is that it gives an error:

```
The method orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X>) in the type Optional<File> is not applicable for the arguments (() -> {})
```

So how can I solve this?

Comment: @JoséPereda The error disappear but I cannot select any file. I must have misunderstood the purpose of StorageService class?

Comment: Remove the `{` and `}` from your lambda, or make sure to use `return`.

Comment: There is no "FileChooser" dialog alike showing up, if that is what you mean. `privateStorage` is the folder root where you will have access to read and write files. When you install the app on mobile, that's the sandboxed area where you can do that.

Comment: @JoséPereda So when I run ´File privateStorage = Services.get(StorageService.class)
                         .flatMap(StorageService::getPrivateStorage)
                         .orElseThrow(() -> new FileNotFoundException("Could not access private storage."));
                     ´ I get access to the ´/´ in Android/Iphone root folder?

Comment: No, with `getPrivateStorage` you get access to a given folder within your _app_ location. See [`getPublicStorage`](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.2/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/StorageService.html#getPublicStorage-java.lang.String-) to get access to other locations like the camera files. And also read this: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files about what you can and can't do on Android.

Comment: @JoséPereda So if I want to save to a fixed folder, in e.g android/iphone storage. Not the external store. How should I write my code? Let's say that I have an app named `MyApp` and it has a sub folder named `MyFolder`. I want to save into that folder.

Comment: If it is part of your app, you should use `getPrivateStorage`, and that's your "root" folder, from where you can have other regular folders and files. If you want to save content from your user interaction, that will be the place to do it. Please read the java doc, and the link I provided. Comments is not for a long Q/A :)

Comment: @JoséPereda Thank you. I will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Optional.empty().orElseThrow(FileNotFoundException::new);
```

or

```
Optional.empty().orElseThrow(()->new FileNotFoundException("Some exception"));
```

or

```
Optional.empty().orElseThrow(() -> {
            return new FileNotFoundException("Some exception");
        });
```

Worth to read: [When are braces optional in Java 8 lambda syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145696/when-are-braces-optional-in-java-8-lambda-syntax)

Comment: Does this open a window where I can select a file?

Comment: @Heretic It is an example of how to solve the error. How to use #orElseThrow